# How can i make group 1 differ based on content in the whole string?

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

In our Python system, I'm trying to isolate the second part of a size to make sure i can save the values separately.

As i got data in tons of different ways i have to take a lot of scenarios into consideration! At the same time our system requires everything to be in group 1 to be identified correctly, which increases the complexity!

This is what i got so far:

```
(?<=[\/\-])\s*([A-Za-z]+|\w+)+?(?!\d*\s*\)|\d*\)|\w*\))(?!\s*[\/\-]+)
```

### Examples

#### working

These are my examples working:

```
110/116
S/M
S / M
S/M(32-34)
110/116(10-12y)
110/116(S/M)
```

#### not working

However my regex only functions correctly on the above examples.

Following 7 are causing issues:

```
S/M / L /XL
S / M / L / XL
S/M / L/XL
S/M/L/XL
S/M/L/XL(30-32)
S/M / L/XL(30-32)
S/M / L / XL(30-32)
```

How can I capture those cases as in below table:

| Case | Input | Expected capture in group 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `S/M / L /XL` | `"L /XL"` |
| 2 | `S / M / L / XL` | `"L / XL"` |
| 3 | `S/M / L/XL` | `"L/XL"` |
| 4 | `S/M/L/XL` | `"L/XL"` |
| 5 | `S/M/L/XL(30-32)` | `"L/XL"` |
| 6 | `S/M / L/XL(30-32)` | `"L/XL"` |
| 7 | `S/M / L / XL(30-32)` | `"L / XL"` |

#### Issue

How can I capture a `"/"` in the middle including the whole part after (like `/XL`) but without any following parentheses (like not the `(30/32)`).

Example for `S/M / L / XL(30-32)` I want to capture `L / XL` only.

Comment: Can you add an example with tests (e.g. using regex101.com or regexplanet.com) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=[/-])\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s*/\s*[A-Z]+)?|\d+)\b(?!\s*[/)-])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKxM03/3). *Details*:

- `(?<=[/-])` - a position immediately preceded with `/` or `-`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z]+(?:\s*/\s*[A-Z]+)?|\d+)` - Group 1: one or more uppercase letters, and then an optional sequence of a `/` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then one or more uppercase letters, or one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\s*[/)-])` - immediately to the right of the current location, there can't be zero or more whitespaces and then either `/`, `)` or `-`.